# Convert MYSQL DATABASE TO MSSQL DATABASE

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, convert, migration

I would like to ask if there is a software that convert all my database from mysql to mssql 2008

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [**Navicat**](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_premium/premium_overview.html) for this (dump/import).

1. Dump sql file from the table in MySQL
2. Use that file to import data into MSSQL table

Navicat offers a 30-day fully functional free trial.

Comment: bro it did not import my  dump sql file